# Query in Batchable class not working

Tags: community, schedulebatch

So We have a Batchable class that calls another apex class which used to send the renewal link for all the contracts of a particular account type.

It was working perfectly fine but now we are seeing issues. It's not sending the email with renewal links to the contracts it's supposed to send. Instead, it is also sending emails to accounts which is not the expected account type.

The only change was we changed the user that runs the scheduled apex job to the new user. Can this affect that?

Here is the snippet of the Batchable class and you can see in the query those are the conditions.

```
global class ContractRenewalBatchable implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    String query;
    Date next60Days;

    /**
    * ContractRenewalBatchable Global
    * @access  global
    */
    global ContractRenewalBatchable(Date d) {

        next60Days = d;

        // 1. Membership Renewal Date is 90 days after/from today and 2. Exclude_from_Renewal_Cycle= FALSE
        // Modified by Anna on 20 May 2016
        // so that it is sent at 90 days and the contract itself is generated at 60 days.
        // Modified to allow processing only for Account.Account_Type__c = Membership
        
        this.query = 'SELECT ID, Name, OwnerId, AccountID, Membership_Renewal_Date__c, Payment_Terms__c, ' +
                'Validity_Start_Date__c, Membership_Category_Lookup__c, Membership_Level__c, ' +
                'BCT_User__c, Account.Name, Account.Account_Type__c ' +
                'FROM Contract ' +
                'WHERE ' +
                'Exclude_from_Renewal_Cycle__c = FALSE ' +
                'AND ' +
                '( Membership_Renewal_Date__c =:next60Days ' +
                'AND (Status = \'Activated\' OR Status = \'Suspended\') ' +
                'AND (Account.Account_Type__c = \'Membership\') ' +
                ')';
                System.debug('Membership - date'+ this.query);
    }

    global ContractRenewalBatchable() {
    
        next60Days = System.today().addDays( 60 );
        
        this.query = 'SELECT ID, Name, OwnerId, AccountID, Membership_Renewal_Date__c, Payment_Terms__c, ' +      
                     'Validity_Start_Date__c, Membership_Category_Lookup__c, Membership_Level__c, ' + 
                     'BCT_User__c, Account.Name, Account.Account_Type__c ' +
                     'FROM Contract ' +
                     'WHERE ' +
                     'Exclude_from_Renewal_Cycle__c = FALSE ' +
                     'AND ' +
                     '( Membership_Renewal_Date__c =:next60Days ' +
                     'AND (Status = \'Activated\' OR Status = \'Suspended\') ' +
                     'AND (Account.Account_Type__c = \'Membership\') ' +
                     ')';
                     System.debug('Membership'+ this.query);
    }

   
    global Database.QueryLocator start( Database.BatchableContext BC ) { 
     //   system.debug('start'); 
        return Database.getQueryLocator( query ); 
    }
    global void execute( Database.BatchableContext BC, Contract[] contracts ) { 
    system.debug('execute'); 
        system.debug('SelectedContracts====>'+ contracts);
        ContractService.renew(contracts); 
    }

  
    global void finish( Database.BatchableContext BC ) {
       //system.debug('finish'); 
    }
    
    WebService static String testBatch( String testArg ) {

        ContractRenewalBatchable c = new ContractRenewalBatchable();
        //system.debug('webservice');
        //system.debug('SelectedWebContracts====>'+ c);
        Database.executeBatch( c, 100 );
        return 'Success';
    }
}
```

```
global class ContractRenewalSchedulable implements Schedulable {

  /**
   * Executing Schedule Job
   * @param   SchedulableContext
   * @return  void
   * @access  global
   */
  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
  {
    ContractRenewalBatchable c = new ContractRenewalBatchable();
    Database.executeBatch(c, 50);
    
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer ready yet, but I do want to say that since your `ContractRenewalBatchable` method is overloaded, you can simplify your code by deleting the `this.query = ...` statement from your second `ContractRenewalBatchable` method (the one with no parameters), and replace it with this call to your first method: `ContractRenewalBatchable(next60days)`. That should make it much easier to maintain if you ever have to change your query.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion will do the same. My problem is as you can see this. query has Account.Account_Type__c = \'Membership\' but in actual it is retrieving contracts of not that type. It was working fine for like 3 years now starting 2021 its behaving abnormally. The only change we did was we changed the user that was assigned to run the scheduled apex to a different one.

Comment: Have you verified that this user has the same (or more generous) access to the `Account` and `Contract` objects (and their fields, etc.)?